# loops define the same element of a fundamental group?

Tags: general-topology

$X=S^{1}\times I$ and $x_0=(1,0)$ where 
$1 \in S^1 \subset\mathbb{C}  $. Define paths by $f(t)=(e^{2\pi it}, 1), p(t)=(1,t), $and $   h(t)=(e^{2\pi it}, t)$. Do the loops $pf\overline{p}$ and  $hf\overline{h}$ define the same element of the fundamental group $ \pi_1(X,x_0)? $

Please give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : $H:X\times I\to X$, defined by $H((x,t),u)=(x,(1-u)t)$, is a deformation retraction of $X$ onto $S^1\times\{0\}\simeq S^1$. Try to use the isomorphism induced by the projection $pr:X\to S^1$ !